# Does IDEA provide high level API (e.g. over HTTP) for actions?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am building browser extension which should be able to trigger IDEA actions (e.g. open file by path).

Currently I have created additional plugin for IDEA which exposes REST API for some actions. It works fine, but I am not sure if this is the good way (at least because I need to manage 2 extensions, I need to handle cases with miltiple IDE instances and so on).

My question is: is there are some exposed API which I can use? I just want to trigger `GotoFile` action and pass filename.

Comment: Please try `http://localhost:63342/api/file`, see http://develar.org/idea-rest-api/#api-Platform-file

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Do you want to add this as answer? Btw, what if I have several IDEs running? E.g. pycharm and idea, which will handle the request? Will they work with the same port?

Comment: @soon IDE will bind to the first available free port, so the second IDE you run will use different port number. Internal web server port can be also set manually per IDE: https://i.imgur.com/HZEnLUg.png.